# If $ n = a b $ and $ a < b $, show that $ a < \sqrt{n} $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For an integer $n\ge 2$, suppose that $n = ab$, where $a, b$ are integers and $a \le b$. Prove that $a\le \sqrt{n}$

For $a=b$, $n=a*a=a^2$ and $\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{a^2}=a\le a$ which is true since $a=a$. How would I go about proving for $a\not=b$? I tried proof by induction, with the base case of $n=2, a=1, b=2$ true since $1\lt \sqrt2$, but the inductive step isn't working well, since it can be true for $n=3, 4, ... k-1$, but the argument of $k-1$ doesn't help prove $k$ from what I can see.

Comment: It's the same as proving that $a^2 \le n$, which is true because $a^2 = a\times a$ can be compared to $a \times b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a,b$ are natural numbers (if not the result is trivial). Now, since $a\leq b$, $a^2\leq ab$. Because of the square root function is increasing this implies $\sqrt{a^2}\leq\sqrt{ab}$, i.e. $a\leq\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Why is it less trivial for naturals ?

Comment: @YvesDaost1 If $a,b$ were negative integers then $a$ would be trivially less or equal than any positive number like $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Ok, I missed that $a,b$ are known to be integers.

Answer (score 1):

From $a\le b$ we deduce $a^2\le ab=n$ (multiplying both members by $a$), hence $a\le\sqrt n$ (taking the square root).

Comment: You need $a$ is not negative, else $a^2 \le ab$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: @quid, if $a$ is negative, $a\le\sqrt n$ certainly holds.

Comment: Obviously. But still your argument is not correct as written.

Comment: @quid: you are right.